# Create a new GitHub repository

Tags: github, repository

I'm looking at [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) link, which referencing [this](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/) link as the first step.

My question would be: can I do the first step from the Terminal (command prompt)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an (empty) project using [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init):

```
mureinuj@computer ~/src/git $ git init myproject
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/mureinik/src/git/myproject/.git/
```

From there on, it's just pushing the (now existing) project into GitHub, as described by the link you provided.

Comment: isn't "git init" for initializing a local repository? If not - how to do that on github?